# Desactivate Youtube Video Player Share button in Full Screen Mode

Tags: css, iframe, youtube, fullscreen

I have deactivated the share button of an embedded YouTube Video player by placing an absolute div on top of the Iframe. It works well, but when the player is in full screen mode, the share button still works. I tried that:

```
@media all and (display-mode: fullscreen) {
    .youtube-icon {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 30vw;
        height: 30vh;
        z-index: 99999999999;
    }
}
```

The div youtube-icon is well on top of the share buttons with a higher z-index, but still the share button is clickable. With the IFrame Player API, it is not possible to remove the share buttons, in my case only deactivating it is good enough. Any suggestions?

Edit: I believe that the div don't appear on top of the player when it is fullscreen, because it was put fullscreen by the fullscreen API (`element.requestFullscreen`) which goes on top of all elements even the fixed ones with a higher z-index). Here is a jsfiddle if someone would like to try a solution: https://jsfiddle.net/Lhgko2wn/3/

Comment: I doubt there is much you can do about this. Sure, you could try and place a div element above the "make fullscreen" control as well, try to catch that click - and then request full screen for an element _containing_ the iframe and your overlays, yourself, that might halfway work ... But when the video is playing and the iframe has focus, I can also simply press `f` to go into fullscreen mode ...

Comment: And if the user goes via "watch on YouTube", they could still share the video from there ... Not sure why preventing this could be so important in the first place, tbh.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks a lot for this comment and ideas. Yes true I did not think about that the user could open it in Youtube, then share it from there. It is a requirement of the task. Maybe I will have to use another video player, like video.js.

Comment: @CBroe, if the user clicks `f`, I could close the fullscreen mode and give it back to the container of the Iframe and my overlays, like this `document.getElementById('player').addEventListener('fullscreenchange', () => { //...});`. But at this point that might be overkill.